# How to change keras backend from theano to tensorflow (weird backend on Windows)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, theano

So my keras backend at C:\Users\Eric is as follow, which is from print(os.path.expanduser('~'))

```
{
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "floatx": "float32",
    "image_data_format": "channels_last",
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

However, whenever I import keras, I got this:

```
Using Theano backend.
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not available, if using conda: `conda install m2w64-toolchain`
```

How do I change it back to 'tensorflow' backend?

I got this switch to theano after trying importing theano.sandbox.cuda (just trying)

Comment: You should be able set `"backend":"tensorflow"` in the file you show above

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the keras_activate.bat file at activate.d/ set to 'theano'. Just empty the file.

Comment: You can do a search in the file system for it